magento 2.4.7 configure cart item no decimals allowed
I upgraded from 2.4.5 to 2.4.7 and now there are some problems with decimal values. Adding to cart of 0.5 qty is no problem, but when i trie to change it to eg. 0.7 in the minicart of by configure page (clicking the pencil) only integers are possible.
I think it is in some javascript validation, but i'm not sure. I searched for hours now, so please help :-)

